# How to add a confirm button before deleting an item?

Tags: javascript, function

after pressing delete button, don't delete the item right away. instead, show a new button confirm delete next to the delete button and only when confirm delete is pressed, delete the item

```
   const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

    function deleteCard(event) {
    const buttonThatGotClicked = event.currentTarget;

      buttonThatGotClicked.closest('.playerCard').remove();
     }
     buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', deleteCard));
```

Comment: Show a new button after clicking the delete button. Delete the item after pressing the new button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

function deleteCard(event) {
  const buttonThatGotClicked = event.currentTarget;
  buttonThatGotClicked.closest('.playerCard').remove();
}

function confirmDelete(e)
{
  //get existing confirm button or create a new one
  const delConfirm = document.querySelector(".deleteConfirm") || document.createElement("button");
  //if class already exists, this is an existing button, don't need initialize it again
  if (!delConfirm.classList.contains("deleteConfirm"))
  {
    //initialize the new button, add class, text, event handler, etc.
    delConfirm.className = "deleteConfirm";
    delConfirm.addEventListener("click", deleteCard);
    delConfirm.textContent = "Confirm delete";
  }
  //insert confirm button after delete button
  if (e.currentTarget.nextSibling)
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.insertBefore(delConfirm, e.currentTarget.nextSibling);
  else
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.appendChild(delConfirm);
}

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', confirmDelete));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="playerCard">mycard1<button class="delete">delete</button></li>
    <li class="playerCard">mycard2<button class="delete">delete</button></li>
    <li class="playerCard">mycard3<button class="delete">delete</button> some text after</li>
    <li class="playerCard">mycard4<button class="delete">delete</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This will never hide the confirm button, unless it's clicked on. If you want hide it, perhaps you could add a click event listener on `body` and check which element was clicked on, if not the confirm button, than hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do this

```js
  let doDelete = window.confirm("delete?")
  if(doDelete) {
    // Delete you stuff
  }
```

The browser will show a confirmation popup before deleting. If you click "OK" the value of doDelete will be true

Comment: thank you fro your answer, but i need another CONFIRM button in-display instead of DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function to confirm it.

```
function myFunction() {
 confirm("Confirm to delete!");
}
```

Comment: Which will do nothing, but annoy the user. Your example makes no sense, it will ask for confirmation, but no matter what user selected it will proceed with deletion anyway.

Comment: This is just an example on how to prompt a confirmation. This is not supposed to be the full function.

Comment: @DerEd Then why would you only half-answer the question?

Comment: Why is it a half answer? "How to add a confirm button before deleting an item?" Was the question. And this is how to add that.

Comment: @DerEd The result from the confirmation box is not used.